# What are these ^^M that I can't replace?

Tags: latex3

If I read with he `v` argument a verbatim string, all newlines are replaced with a token `^^M` (seems like it is a carriage return in latex). The problem is that when I write this down to a file, it actually writes `^^M` instead of a new line. I tried to replace it with `\tl_replace_all:Nnn {^^M} {^^J}`, but it gives me an error…

What is this ^^M that I cannot remove? How could I get rid of it?

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
%\def^^M{AA}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str
\NewDocumentCommand{\robExtCacheMeCode}{O{}+v}{%
  {% Group
    %% We store the input in a non-string element for efficiently implementing "auto forward"
    \tl_set:Nn \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str {#2}
    % fails with error Runaway argument?
    % \tl_replace:Nnn \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str {^^M} {^^J}
    \str_show:N \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str
    \begin{flushleft}\ttfamily%
      \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str
    \end{flushleft}%
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\noindent This works:\robExtCacheMeCode{42 % 8}.

\noindent This fails, first because newlines are turned into caret caret M, but also becase characters like :\robExtCacheMeCode{
  Hey I am a multi-line text with { } # foo []<> % many caracters, including
  newlines like her.  
}.


\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
I tried to apply the advice of David Carlisle, I managed to turn them into space, but not into newline…

Try 1:

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str
\tl_new:N \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl
\def\foo{^^J}
\NewDocumentCommand{\robExtCacheMeCode}{O{}+v}{%
  {% Group
    %% We store the input in a non-string element for efficiently implementing "auto forward"
    \tl_set_rescan:Nnn \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl {
      \char_set_active_eq:nN { `\^^M } \foo
      \cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab
    } {#2}
    \str_set:Ne \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str {\tl_to_str:e {\__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl}}
    \str_show:N \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str
    \begin{flushleft}\ttfamily%
      \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str
    \end{flushleft}%
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\noindent This works:\robExtCacheMeCode{42 % 813}.

\noindent This fails, first because newlines are turned into caret caret M, but also becase characters like :\robExtCacheMeCode{
  Hey
  I am a multi-line text
  with { } # foo []<> % many caracters, including
  newlines like here.
}.


\end{document}
```

Try 2:

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str
\tl_new:N \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl
\def\foo{^^J}
\NewDocumentCommand{\robExtCacheMeCode}{O{}+v}{%
  {% Group
    %% We store the input in a non-string element for efficiently implementing "auto forward"
    \char_set_active_eq:nN { `\^^M } \foo
    \tl_set:Nx \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl {#2}
    \str_set:Ne \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str {\tl_to_str:e {\__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl}}
    \str_show:N \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str
    \begin{flushleft}\ttfamily%
      \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_str
    \end{flushleft}%
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\noindent This works:\robExtCacheMeCode{42 % 813}.

\noindent This fails, first because newlines are turned into caret caret M, but also becase characters like :\robExtCacheMeCode{
  Hey
  I am a multi-line text
  with { } # foo []<> % many caracters, including
  newlines like here.
}.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^^M` is control-M, character 13 (carriage return).
It is normally added automatically by TeX at the ends of input lines but if you add one explicitly when it has the default catcode 5 it acts very similar to a comment, the rest of the line is discarded. The difference being that it will add white space.

---

the `v` argument type records ends of lines as catcode 12 `^^M` so you can for example replace them by `\par`  Note use `tl` not `str` for variables that can hold csname tokens.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
%\def^^M{AA}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\robExtCacheMeCode}{O{}+v}{%
  {% Group
    %% We store the input in a non-string element for efficiently implementing "auto forward"
    \tl_set:Nn \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl {#2}
    % fails with error Runaway argument?
    \tl_replace_all:Nen \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl {\char_generate:nn{13}{12}} {\par}
    \tl_show:N \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl
    \begin{flushleft}\ttfamily%
      \__robExt_tmp_contain_code_tl
    \end{flushleft}%
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\noindent This works:\robExtCacheMeCode{42 % 8}.

  \noindent This fails, first because newlines are turned into caret caret M, but also becase characters like
:\robExtCacheMeCode{
  Hey I am a multi-line text with { } # foo []<> % many caracters, including
  newlines like her.  
}.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get rid of it? `\tl_replace_all` fails on that specific case.

Comment: Hum… do you have a code for that? I tried my best (see my edit with two tries), but without much success with `\def\foo{^^J}\char_set_active_eq:nN { `\^^M } \foo`, `\tl_set:Nx`… I managed to turn them into space but not into newlines ^^J.

Comment: @tobiasBora I extended the answer in last edit

Comment: @tobiasBora you do not want `^^J` they do not do anything useful in TeX typeset text. They do force a newline in `\write`.

Comment: replace_all fails for the same reason as if you tried to replace a `%` if you go `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \foo {%}{X}` then you would have commented out `}{X}`  same happens with `^^M`